# Run program with group execution permission

Tags: bash, permissions, users

I want to run program with execution permissions set to group. Unfortunately bash says "Permission denided".

How can I run program as user different that root without giving ownership to this user? But relay on group permissions. Is it possible?

More details:
I'm trying to run program as user 'user1'. This user belongs to group 'users'.
Program permissions are:

```
-rwxr-xr-- 1 root users 4121 Jan 24  2013 /opt/apache-jmeter-2.9/bin/jmeter
```

Answer (score 3):

See the sudo man page for more information. Try:

```
sudo -u user1 -g users /opt/apache-jmeter-2.9/bin/jmeter
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But is it possible to setup permission that sudo will be not required?

Comment: @Max: I haven't used it, but I believe GNU userv has similar functionality. http://www.gnu.org/software/userv/

Answer (score 0):

`user1` must be a user who is part of the `users` group. To add it to `users` group, use the following command:

```
sudo adduser user1 users
```

After this, `user1` should be able to execute `/opt/apache-jmeter-2.9/bin/jmeter` without any other permissions.

Comment: Already done, but doesn't work.